# Interacting with Internet Explorer's blacklist

Tags: internet-explorer, dns, phishing

I have a list of 100,000 domains and I need to identify which ones are blocked by IE for phishing, malware, etc. Are there any applications that interact with IE or solutions that can help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) and automate navigating to all those URLs.

Comment: Would that be able to handle 100k domains in a reasonable time span?

Comment: I lack the expertise to say, but assuming 5 seconds per request it would take about a year.  A couple months if its 1 second per request.

Answer (score 1):

Try this? Not IE specific, but its a blacklist API.

http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/

Comment: I need IE's blacklist, specifically. I've already assembled a blacklist from Google's API. :D

Comment: Best of luck! I think it might be a hard one.